# Side by side button or stacked?

Tags: website-design, buttons

In terms of user experience, which layout of buttons would work better? This would basically be a landing page.

Side by side?

[image]

Or stacked?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell because there isn't the context of the rest of the page. Your typical landing page for a SaaS or product has buttons side by side.

However, one thing to point out is that both of your buttons are the same color and have equal visual weight, which implies they have equal importance. You should have one primary call-to-action and one secondary call-to-action. The secondary should be related to the primary, but represent less of a commitment. It should also be less visually prominent. It depends on the design, but most primary calls to action are bright and stand out, while the secondary call is muted or gray or even just a link rather than a button.